Inserting TextAnnotation in graph c#
IMAGE
I creating simple graph with line as average (sample only), I have a code in HorizontalLineAnnotation (color red line) and TextAnnotation but the problem is that, the TextAnnotation not working properly.
Here my code in HorizontalLineAnnotation and TextAnnotation .

private void annptaion()
{
//insert line
HorizontalLineAnnotation hl = new HorizontalLineAnnotation();
                    hl.AllowMoving = false;
                    hl.IsInfinitive = true;
                    //hl.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    hl.AnchorY = Convert.ToDouble(2);//row line
                    hl.AxisX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
                    hl.AxisY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
                    hl.ClipToChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name; hl.LineColor = Color.Red; hl.LineWidth = 1;//make line
                    hl.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
                    chart1.Annotations.Add(hl);

//insert text
TextAnnotation ta = new TextAnnotation();
                    
                    ta.AxisX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
                    ta.AxisY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
                    ta.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
                    ta.AnchorAlignment = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
                    ta.Text = "average (sample)";
                    ta.ClipToChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name; ta.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    chart1.Annotations.Add(ta);
}


I use the code above for displaying text in the line, but it's not working properly. I want to display the text either inside of the graph or outside of the graph.

In your code, you only bound the annotation to the axes but did not specify its exact position.
Add:
 ta.AnchorX = 2;
 ta.AnchorY = 0.5;

AnchorX/Y: Gets or sets the X/Y coordinate to which the annotation is anchored.
And this is my code, please notice that use "  annotation.AnchorAlignment = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;"
public partial class Form1 : Form
{



 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();
    chart1.Annotations.Clear();

    ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea("ChartArea2");
    chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

    Series series = new Series("Series1")
    {
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    };
    chart1.Series.Add(series);

    // add data
    series.Points.AddXY(1, 1);
    series.Points.AddXY(2, 3);
    series.Points.AddXY(3, 2);
    series.Points.AddXY(4, 5);
    series.Points.AddXY(5, 4);


    AddAnnotations();
}

private void AddAnnotations()
{
  
    HorizontalLineAnnotation hl = new HorizontalLineAnnotation
    {
        AllowMoving = false,
        IsInfinitive = true,
        AnchorY = 3.0, 
        AxisX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX,
        AxisY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY,
        ClipToChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name,
        LineColor = Color.Red,
        LineWidth = 2,
        IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false
    };
    chart1.Annotations.Add(hl);


    // add  TextAnnotation
    TextAnnotation annotation = new TextAnnotation();
    annotation.Text = "this is an Annotation";
    annotation.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
    annotation.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    annotation.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
    annotation.AnchorAlignment = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
annotation.AxisX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    annotation.AxisY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    annotation.AnchorX = 3; 
    annotation.AnchorY = 2; 


    chart1.Annotations.Add(annotation);
}

private Chart chart1;

}

Good day Zhenning Zhang, I tried your code and same it's not work. I try ta.AnchorX = 2;
ta.AnchorY = 0.5;

I created a WinForms application and tried it out, and it does work. I'll share my code for your reference. If it still doesn't work for you, you can try creating the chart and annotations from the designer.

AND i dont know why :  I used      "ta.AnchorAlignment = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft ;"  like you did and the annotation moved to the right of my chart, so i changed it to  ta.AnchorAlignment = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;

Good day Zhenning Zhang, Your code is usefull.,Thank you so much for your code and it's work for me :)
